# Apply effects to multiple clips (automation/batch/macro?) in Adobe Premiere CC

Tags: premiere, automation

I have a Folder with dozens of Action Camera Clips. For each clip, I'd like to apply the same effects (*lens distortion correction*, *warp stabilizer* and *color correction*). But I want to create individual output clips, so starting with 50 Clips in Folder *Source*, I want to end up with 50 recoded matching clips in Folder *Target*, keep File names.

This is a painfully repeating job doing that clip by clip. Do you see any method of automation I can apply here?

Comment: There is a scripting language for Premiere called Extendscript, but Adobe refuse to release any documentation for it. So writing something to do it automatically might take as long as doing it manually (never stopped me, but there you go). Please, complain to Adobe, and in the future some developer will make a tool to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

you can add\modify the filters on one clip then from the effects tab select the effects > "save presets" and apply those to the other clips.[image]